# Locking two methods and ensure that only on thread is calling one method

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In a class I've two methods:

- Method1(): void
- Method2(): void

This class can be accessed by multiple threads.
How can I realise, if "thread1" call "Method1", that "thread2" is waiting in "Method2" or in "Method1". This logic should also work, if "thread2" is calling "Method2", that "thread1" is waiting in "Method1" or "Method2"

My idea is this:

```
private object _lock = new object();

void Method1() {
 lock(_lock){
  //TODO: do something
 }
}

void Method2() {
 lock(_lock){
  //TODO: do something
 }
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: Do you want to *know* if some other thread is waiting or do you want to ensure that only one thread can run either of the methods at any one given time?

Comment: I want to ensure that only one thread can run either of the methods.

Comment: Then your method is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work after your clarification in comments.

With the given code you will:

1. Ensure only one thread can execute *either* `Method1` or `Method2` at the same time

   1. If one thread is inside `Method1`, other threads will wait if they try to call either `Method1` or `Method2`.
2. If `Method1` calls into `Method2` or vice versa, this will also work as the same thread can lock the same object more than once.

   In other words, this is *not* a deadlock:

   ```
   lock (x)
       lock (x)
           ....
   ```

So your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do on same object, You can use Monitor. Monitor allows re-entrancy

Comment: So, with a "Monitor" I can ensure that only on thread can run either of the methods?

Comment: lock() is [syntactic sugar for Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029829/13744), but with the Monitor.Exit code written out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WaitOne() function of an AutoResetEvent to allow only one function to access resources at a time, when it's finished called Set().

Example here: [Synchronizing two threads with AutoResetEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481664/synchronizing-two-threads-with-autoresetevent)

MSDN Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your methods should be Synchronized. See [C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-sharp-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword) to get an idea on how to do it in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Since you're locking on the same object, only one `lock { }` block will be executed at a given time.

> How can I realise, if "thread1" call "Method1", that "thread2" is waiting in "Method2" or in "Method1". This logic should also work, if "thread2" is calling "Method2", that "thread1" is waiting in "Method1" or "Method2"

The logic will work. But not sure what you're trying to ask here.